# Security issue with custom search provider for Windows 7

Tags: security, search, windows-7, filepath, custom-search-provider

I built a search provider for Windows 7, running on **localhost**. (using .osdx file and RSS web site)
the  element in the returned RSS contains **local** file path.

example: `<link>c:\windows\win.ini</link>`

The problem is that the files shown in the search result window with the following message:

> This item was blocked because of your Internet security settings

[image: This item was blocked because of your Internet security settings]

How to prevent this security restriction?

Answer (score 0):

you have to add the intranet zone and modify its security settings to allow this content.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/174360  -- security zone registry settings

Comment: I agree, but would like to add a link to the custom search documentation - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc891507(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: What do you mean in "add the intranet zone"? there is already intranet zone in IE. What is the exact security setting I should change there? I tried to change 1805 and 1806 to 1 in the registry in zone 0 and zone 1 with no luck.